# Phpseclib Issue - SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE: publickey * PHP

Tags: php, phpseclib

I got some issue using phpseclib,is like my second post, and I've figured it out partially but i can't get it working properly...

Anyway here is the issue:
I've installed phpseclib using composer, and I'm using this test script in order to connect to my VPS hosted by amazon, that is giving me some troubles So what I understood is that I need to use the .pem key file in order to authenticate. Easy right?

That's the script:

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__ . 'vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib');
$loader->register();

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

//$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key = new RSA();
$ret = $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('Key_1.pem'));

if(!$ret){
    echo "loadKey failed\n";
    exit;
}

// Domain can be an IP too
$ssh = new SSH2('ip.ip.ip.ip');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    print_r($ssh->errors);
    exit('Login Failed');

}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');

?>
```

So here is some issues that I'm getting:

1- Crypt_RSA isn't working, Class not found (RSA class doesn't give me any errors)
2- Using RSA I'm getting this error

```
SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE: publickey ) Login Failed
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the path for the include?

phpseclib is located in:

```
vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib
```

Then I've the others folder...

I don't know! Please someone help me out!

Comment: to check if the path is right, does `var_dump(file_get_contents('Key_1.pem'))` give you the content of your file as expected?

Comment: You don't need to do the `$loader` since you're doing `vendor/autoload.php`. Anyway, can you connect to the server using that same key using PuTTY or another SSH client?

Comment: @neubert yep I ssh to it using a terminal, with the 2 commands that the ec2 documentation give to me!

chmod 400 Key_1.pem

ssh -I "Key_1.pem" ubuntu@ip.somestrings etc

And it all works

Comment: @ArSeN Yep I get a bunch of characters so, the path file is alright!

Comment: @ManzoFilippo I dug a bit deeper into this and got myself an EC2 instance to try this out. I installed phpseclib in the most recent version (2.0.11), and what can I say, your code works perfectly fine for me. Could you please check that: 1) your Key_1.pem does actually contain your private key and not the public key? and 2) that you changed `!$ssh->login('username', $key)` the "username" part to the actual username, presumably "ubuntu" from your previous comment

Comment: @ManzoFilippo any luck yet?

Comment: @ArSeN Yeah got it working, I'm out office right now, so i can't be specific about the solution, but what I recall i had some issue with composer, so I just did the thing that most people should do before doing anything else "Have you tried switchin it of and on again?" so I just run another "instance" of composer, reinstalled the phpseclib again, and it worked!